# Easy way to convert sfc_POINT into RasterLayer?

Tags: r, raster, geo, r-sf

I am using the library `sf` for spatial data in R. I want to use the `SpaDES::splitRaster()` method to split up a grid made with `sf::st_make_grid()` into many tiles. As far as I know, neither the `sf` or the `raster` library support such an operation.

However, `st_make_grid()` returns an object of `sfc_POINT`, but `splitRaster()` requires an object of type `RasterLayer` (for example).

Is there a method in `sf` (or `raster`, but I'd prefer to stay within `sf`) that I can use to quickly convert `sfc_POINT` into a `RasterLayer`, ideally without loading `rgdal` and `rgeos`?

Comment: `splitRaster(raster(SpatialGrid((points2grid(as_Spatial(st_make_grid(what = "centers")))))))`

Comment: Thank you. This looks complicated but is probably the "easiest" way. Would be cool if `sf` had such a `splitRaster` method...

Comment: @hrbrmstr any news on this operation?